# SceneKit editor, how to resize objects without using inspector?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, scenekit

In most 3D editors, there is the ability to resize an object by grabbing the edge, or something similar. However, the SceneKit editor in Xcode seems to require that I set the numerical dimensions manually in the Inspector. Am I missing something? This seems like a major omission.

Comment: This comes down to the fact that the SceneKit editor in Xcode is not a replacement for a 3D modeling tool. It is there to create your scenes from various assets you get from those tools and make them ready to use in your code.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not trying to create complex objects though, I just want to place walls of varying sizes. ‍♂️